# What parts/gears should be replaced if taking tranny down?

Tags: transmission

I have a bad 3rd gear synchro on my 2007 v6 6 speed manual Tacoma, which results in grinding when shifting 2nd->3rd gear if not done super carefully.  As I feel confident in my mechanical aptitude, having completed many smaller jobs to this point, I am eying a complete tranny rebuild as my next challenge.

However, taking down a tranny and taking it apart is quite an ordeal so I might as well replace everything that should be replaced at that point rather than just the 3rd gear synchro.  Can you help me identify a list of items that I should replace?

Comment: I haven't been able to find (as of yet) a rebuild kit for your vehicle's transmission (found one for the 5-speed). Hopefully someone can come up with the information for you.

Comment: do you think it will be possible to remove the tranny with a tranny jack without raising the truck on a hydraulic jack or at least maybe just raise it on jackstands or ramps ?  it has enough clearance for me to get under it without raising but not sure if that is enough for the tranny+jack and to pull it out.

Comment: [I'm having a similar problem, so I'd love to hear if you've found anything out since you last posted. The problem I'm having is with my fifth gear, which is making the transition to reverse a little more difficult. I probably won't do the repair myself, but I do want to know what will need to be replaced.](http://www.drivetrainpartslasvegas.com/discount_transmission_parts_s/2396.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I had the '05 version of your truck.

Here's my old list out of a notebook.

- All synchro rings.  2nd, 3rd and 5th are multi piece.  1st to 2nd and 3rd to 4th are coil springs
- Roller bearings (Input shaft and Main Shaft, Counter Shaft)
- Front and rear seals
- Pocket Bearing
- ALL Gaskets
- Shift fork inserts

I"m sure you were hoping for something more comprehensive but this is all I really have for you.  Good luck. It's a fun job.

Comment: I would also suggest replacing the blocking ring and gear for the for the gear that's grinding. The teeth that make the engagement may be damaged or worn from the grinding. Just as a precaution.